# How to display pictures in the project resource?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a set of small icons and hope to display them in my application when certain condition occurs, for example on sunny day, I display the sunny icon.

I can add the jpg files in the picture, and they seem to be uploaded to phone when I deploy the app. However, I don't know how to access these jpgs in my program.

Could someone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this post about content and resources: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action

To summarize: You should mark your images with a Build Action of Content or Resource, preferably Content. Now you can reference the Content from your Xaml or in code.

Answer (score 2):

If the Build Action for your image resources is set to **Content**, then you just specify the `Source` property for the `Image` control to the relative path to your images:

```
this._image.Source = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("/Images/myImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display pictures using the Image element:

```
<Image Source="/MyImage.png" Visibility="Visible"/>
```

If you want to switch images according to conditions then you can create multiple images and change each of their Visibility states - or (more preferable) you can create a single image element and change its Source.

Quite how you do this depends on whether you are using databinding or working directly with the UIElements in code behind.

Comment: I first used images by looking at the code in http://4square.codeplex.com/ and seeing how that worked (it shows icons in the first menu)

Comment: And if you're feeling in the mood for Ruby, then these scripts also show Images - but mainly from downloaded content rather than from embedded images http://script.iron7.com/#/Script/ByTag?tag=image